# Tab content does not scroll to top on select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

pardon if it's a simple issue to solve or it has already been solved here. But, I just can not figure it out. The issue is, I have two tabs. While in the content page if I call content.scrollToTop() then it works fine. But, I am not sure about how to scroll to the top of a tab content page when the tab is clicked or selected?

```
 <ion-tabs> 
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

  <ion-tab-button tab="home" **(click)="scrollToTop()"**>
    <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    <!-- <ion-badge>6</ion-badge> -->
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
    <ion-label>About</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <!-- <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
    <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
  </ion-tab-button> -->

</ion-tab-bar>
```

```
  import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';
  import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.page.scss'],
  })
  export class TabsPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
  constructor( public event:Events) { }


  scrollToTop(){
  this.content.scrollToTop();
   }

  }
```

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you already done? Where does your problem start?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie here is my code.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep separate method

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" (click)="myMethod()"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" (click)="myMethod2()"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" (click)="myMethod3()"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

then write your logic

```
myMethod()
{
 this.content.scrollToTop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the `ionViewWillEnter` event which can be explained further in the Ionic Page Life Cycle documentation:

- [Ionic Page Life Cycle - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)

If your page was tabs2 then the code could look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: './tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab2.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(IonContent) private content: IonContent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
  }

}
```